# Gain badge, lose rep?

Tags: discussion, reputation, reputation-history

Perhaps this is a strange coincidence, but it appears I have lost reputation because I gained badges.  When I went to bed yesterday, I had 1280 rep. on SO. When I logged in tonight, I was told that I received the Tenacious badge 3 hrs earlier.  I also noticed my rep was 1278.  I went straight to the Review/Triage queue, and I was 6 reviews short of the Reviewer badge, so I worked on some reviews, and earned the badge.  Then my rep dropped to 1276.  When I look at my rep history, I don't see any -2s, or any indication that my rep changed at all today.  What gives?

Is there any way for me to figure out what actually happened?  Not that -4 rep is a big deal, but it seems like a glitch.

Comment: Two posts you got two rep each from for an approved suggested edit have been deleted recently - hence the reversal and the -4 you see.

Comment: Ah, ok.  Thanks very much for the info!  That was quite an astonishing coincidence then, regarding the badges.

Answer (score 5):

I went through your reputation page and I could not see anything that would have made it gone down, but I can only see the public reputation page. I added up all of your days of rep gains and I got 1276. According to your profile the last rep you gained was 2 days ago and for 35 points.

The only thing I can think of is that you had a suggested edit and it was approved and later on, that post was deleted. In that case you would get a -2 rep loss that you and mods might be able to see on your [reputation page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5530155/gariepy?tab=reputation&sort=time&page=1). This is the only thing that makes sense to me if you know your rep went down.

Answer (score 4):

Badge gains have **little** or **no relationship** to reputation.

Your lost reputation is likely due to that a post or edit you gained reputation of has been removed, or that the user who gave you the reputation points have been deleted.